# Running npm run scss

Tags: css, sass, less

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/user/bootstrap4/conFusion/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 265 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "confusion",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": "1'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-30T15_13_13_421Z-debug.log

Comment: you have issues with your package.json

Comment: We need to see your package.json file

Comment: Full Listing @ http://drmco.ltd/stackquery/courserapackageJSON.html